# gcc path not valid when installing VMWare Tools from VMWare Workstation 7.1.1 build-282343 on Debian squeeze

Tags: vmware, debian, debian-squeeze

I am trying to install VMWare tools on Debian Squeeze.

My error:

```
Before you can compile modules, you need to have the following installed... 

make
gcc
kernel headers of the running kernel

Searching for GCC...
The path "/usr/bin/gcc" is not valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [yes]
```

uname -a:

```
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sat Sep 18 02:14:45 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

dpkg -l | grep make

```
ii  make                                 3.81-8                               An utility for Directing compilation.
```

dpkg -l | grep gcc

```
ii  gcc                                  4:4.4.4-2                            The GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.4                              4.4.4-8                              The GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.4-base                         4.4.4-8                              The GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc1                              1:4.4.4-8                            GCC support library
```

whereis gcc

```
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc
```

Comment: Make sure you also have libglib2.0-0 installed.

Answer (score 20):

Running this command fixed the problem:

```
sudo aptitude install gcc-4.3 make linux-headers-`uname -r` -y
```

Comment: @WarrenP `make` is one of the packages that needs to be installed (see edit history, revision 4), not a separate command. I've reverted your edit.

Answer (score 5):

Like Guillaume said in OP's comment:

```
sudo aptitude install libglib2.0-0
```

Comment: Had the same problem on a clean debian installation. The library was missing.